# Why is fuse not using the class supplied in file_class

Tags: python, fuse

I have a python fuse project based on the Xmp example in the fuse documentation. I have included a small piece of the code to show how this works. For some reason get_file does get called and the class gets created, but instead of fuse calling .read() on the class from get_file (file_class) fuse keeps calling Dstorage.read() which defeats the purpose in moving the read function out of that class.

```
class Dstorage(Fuse, Distributor):
    def get_file(self, server, path, flags, *mode):
        pass
        # This does some work and passes back an instance of
        # a class very similar to XmpFile

    def main(self, *a, **kw):
        self.file_class = self.get_file
        return Fuse.main(self, *a, **kw)
```

I have my code hosted on launchpad, you can download it with this command.
<strike>bzr co https://code.launchpad.net/~asa-ayers/+junk/dstorage</strike>
bzr branch lp:~asa-ayers/dstorage/trunk

**solution:**
I used a proxy class that subclasses the one I needed and in the constructor I get the instance of the class I need and overwrite all of the proxy's methods to simply call the instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the Fuse class (which is a maze of twisty little passages creating method proxies), I see this bit (which is a closure used to create a setter inside `Fuse.MethodProxy._add_class_type`, line 865):

```
        def setter(self, xcls):

            setattr(self, type + '_class', xcls)

            for m in inits:
                self.mdic[m] = xcls

            for m in proxied:
                if hasattr(xcls, m):
                    self.mdic[m] = self.proxyclass(m)
```

When you do `self.file_class = self.get_file`, this gets called with `self.get_file`, which is a bound method. The loop over proxied attributes is expecting to be able to get the attributes off the class you set, to put them into its `mdic` proxy dictionary after wrapping them, but they aren't there, because it's a bound method, rather than a class. Since it can't find them, it reverts to calling them on `Dstorage`.

So, long story short, you can't use a callable that returns an instance (kind of a pseudo-class) instead of a class here, because Fuse is introspecting the object that you set to find the methods it should call.

You need to assign a class to `file_class` - if you need to refer back to the parent instance, you can use the nested class trick they show in the docs.